# Retrieving primary contact's email address (query not working properly)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've been trying without success to retrieve all the contact information of a certain customer, given their account number (i wanted to obtain the primary email set for that customer - if any)

This is my first time using EBS and there are a lot of tables and i think i am missing something because my query is not working properly. It shows me different emails but i think it is not correct.

Can you please help me with this?

This is my query:

```
SELECT hp.party_name customer_name,hca.account_number, hca.cust_account_id
       customer_id, --hcsu.LOCATION customer_site_name, 
       hcas.cust_acct_site_id customer_site_id, hl.address1,hl.address2,
       hl.address3,hl.address4,hl.city, hl.province, hl.postal_code,
       NVL ((SELECT DISTINCT phone_number
             FROM hz_contact_points
             WHERE status = 'A'
             AND primary_flag = 'Y'
             AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
             AND contact_point_type = 'PHONE'
             AND owner_table_id = hcas.cust_acct_site_id
             AND ROWNUM = 1), NULL) phone_number,
       NVL ((SELECT DISTINCT email_address
             FROM hz_contact_points
             WHERE status = 'A'
             AND primary_flag = 'Y'
             AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
             AND contact_point_type = 'EMAIL'
             AND owner_table_id = hcas.cust_acct_site_id
             AND ROWNUM = 1), NULL) email,
       hcas.status site_status,
       DECODE (hcas.attribute5, 'PUP', 'Y', 'N') usage_type,
       hca.status account_status
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca,
     apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas,
     apps.hz_parties hp,
     apps.hz_party_sites hps,
     apps.hz_locations hl
WHERE hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
AND hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
AND hps.location_id = hl.location_id
AND hps.party_id = hp.party_id
AND hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
AND hca.account_number='number account'
```

Comment: I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) Although you see the problem as a query, we only see the query but have no clues about the data that the query is utterly dependent on. Without data we just don't know what the exact fix is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend avoiding correlated subqueries in select clauses, they are often a cause of poor query performance. I also **suspect** that the correlation used currently may be to the wrong table `owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'` indicates that this data should relate to the table `apps.hz_party_sites` but I cannot be certain of this as I have no knowledge of your data

Below I have suggested a single "derived table" subquery in place of the correlations currently in use.

```
SELECT
    hp.party_name                              customer_name
  , hca.account_number
  , hca.cust_account_id                        
  , customer_id
    --, hcsu.LOCATION customer_site_name
  , hcas.cust_acct_site_id                     customer_site_id
  , hcp.phone_number
  , hcp.email_address
  , hl.address1
  , hl.address2
  , hl.address3
  , hl.address4
  , hl.city
  , hl.province
  , hl.postal_code
  , hcas.status                                site_status
  , DECODE( hcas.attribute5, 'PUP', 'Y', 'N' ) usage_type
  , hca.status                                 account_status
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            owner_table_id
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'PHONE' then phone_number end) phone_number
          , max(case when contact_point_type = 'EMAIL' then email_address end) email_address
        FROM hz_contact_points
        WHERE status = 'A'
        AND primary_flag = 'Y'
        AND owner_table_name = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES'
        AND contact_point_type IN ('EMAIL','PHONE')
        GROUP BY 
            owner_table_id
    ) hcp ON hcas.cust_acct_site_id = hcp.owner_table_id /* not sure of this join */
    AND hcp.rn = 1
WHERE hcas.status = 'A'
AND hps.status = 'A'
AND hca.status = 'A'
AND hca.account_number = 'number account'
;
```

by the way `NVL(column,NULL)` does not achieve anything, if `column` is already NULL then it will be NULL without needing NVL

Additionally over 25 years ago ANSI standards formalized explicit join syntax, and this should be adopted as well.

---

converting your "joins", I always start by dividing the from line at the commas:

```
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
   , apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas
   , apps.hz_parties hp
   , apps.hz_party_sites hps
   , apps.hz_locations hl
```

Then replace the commas with `INNER JOIN` and place `ON` at the end of each such row

```
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON
```

Then I cut the joining predicates from the where clause to their needed location taking care that each join now refers to a table ABOVE (I had to move one due to this)

```
FROM apps.hz_cust_accounts hca
INNER JOIN apps.hz_cust_acct_sites_all hcas ON hca.cust_account_id = hcas.cust_account_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_party_sites hps ON hcas.party_site_id = hps.party_site_id
INNER JOIN apps.hz_locations hl ON hps.location_id = hl.location_id
/* had to move this down */
INNER JOIN apps.hz_parties hp ON hps.party_id = hp.party_id
```